# how to group by with order by on somewhat complex mysql query

Tags: mysql, join, union

```
(SELECT dtable.*, new_apps.top as t1 FROM app_detailsvvv as dtable INNER JOIN new_apps ON
new_apps.trackId=dtable.trackId WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM compositions as dtablev
WHERE parent='169469' AND trackId=dtable.trackId AND new_apps.top > 0)>0) UNION
(SELECT *, 301 FROM app_detailsvvv as dtable WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM compositions   
as dtablev WHERE parent='169469' AND trackId=dtable.trackId)>0) ORDER BY t1 ASC, trackName 
ASC LIMIT 0,12
```

this query brings me duplicates, how can I group by it by trackId ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place trackid as part of your SELECT statement ...

```
SELECT new_apps.trackId,
       ..etc...
..
..

GROUP BY 1
```

Make sure the rest of your SELECT items (including the sub-SQL query) have been aggregated - such as MAX, FIRST, SUM or something that groups them into a single result.

Comment: both queries in the union have the field trackId selected, yet I can't group by with an order by in place

Comment: You cannot group by and order by at the same time because group by does the ordering based on the order of your selects from left to right. Just use group by